# Core Data results into a SwiftUI Picker view without preselecting an option

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui, picker

I am fetching data from Core Data and displaying it in a Picker, this view is built in SwiftUI. I struggled at first to get the selection to work from the picker, but found if I preselect the first object from my fetch result, in the view's init, the picker selection works.

What I want is to be able to load my data into the Picker, but not preselect one of the objects. Again, if I update the code below so nothing is preselected, then I can't select anything. I get to the screen of options, but when I tap one, nothing happens, I just get that little flash on the row. I have to hit the Back button to get back to the form view.

Any ideas for how to make loading Core Data into a Picker without preselecting one of the options work?

-Thanks!

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct RecordCreateview: View {
    @FetchRequest private var actions: FetchedResults<Actions>
    @State private var selectedAction: Actions

    init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Actions> = Actions.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Actions.action, ascending: true)]
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        self._actions = FetchRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
        do {
            let fetchResult = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            self._selectedAction = State(initialValue: fetchResult[0])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Problem fetching Action records.")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Picker("Select action", selection: $selectedAction){
                    ForEach(actions) { action in
                        if action.title == true {
                            Text("\(action.action!)").tag(action)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can’t answer in full right now. I’m on my phone. But my initial thought would be to add an additional entry in your `actions` array and use that as the initial selection. As a sort of dummy action. Possibly. Or can you make selectedAction an optional and set it as nil to begin with?

Comment: Yeah, that's a hack I thought about. Problem is users will be able to add and delete records to and from this datastore, so it's a no-go in that case. Thanks though!

Comment: I think that if you just set the `selectedAction` to a non-existent `Actions` in `init(...)` 
such as: 
`self._selectedAction = State(initialValue: Actions(context: context))` there 
should not be any pre-selected object in the picker.

Comment: @workingdog, it looks like that worked. You should post it as an answer so I can mark as the selected answer. Thank you!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing CoreData Entities from form picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69454136/choosing-coredata-entities-from-form-picker)

Comment: I deleted my answer, because @loremipsum
 answer using an optional is more appropriate. Make sure you add the  tag as such: `Text("\(action.action!)").tag(action as? Actions)` .

Comment: @workingdog when I add that conditional cast to the tag, I get the following warning: Conditional cast from 'FetchedResults<Actions>.Element' (aka 'Actions') to 'Actions' always succeeds
So I don't believe it's needed since action already is an Actions.

Comment: @loremipsum It did not, when I changed my code over to model that answer, I was back to not being able to select an option from the Picker.

Comment: @workingdog, it's up to you, if you want to put your answer back in, I'll select it as the correct answer. Yours is the solution I'm going with.

Comment: @dbDev did you change your `@State`? to  `@State private var selectedAction: Actions? = nil`?. The type in the tag has to match the State type.

Comment: @loremipsum Yep, I modeled the all of the code from that post and it reverted me back to not being able to select anything at all.

Comment: I've un-deleted my answer, and included the code I use with `selectedAction` as an optional. Let us know if that part works for you.

Comment: @workingdog Thanks! The only change I made to the above, original code was the single line you suggested, changing the initialization of selectedAction to:
self._selectedAction = State(initialValue: Actions(context: context))
I did not need to make selectedAction optional or use the coalescing operator in the tag.
If you remove the optionals below, I'll accept the answer. You also need to add the self._selectedActions line of code to the init. :D -Thanks!

Comment: updated my answer, and removed the optional `selectedAction`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the selectedAction to a non-existent `Actions` in `init(...)` like this:

```
self._selectedAction = State(initialValue: Actions(context: context))
```

that will not set a pre-selected object in the picker.

```
struct RecordCreateview: View {
    @FetchRequest private var actions: FetchedResults<Actions>
    @State private var selectedAction: Actions

    init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Actions> = Actions.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Actions.action, ascending: true)]
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        self._actions = FetchRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
        self._selectedAction = State(initialValue: Actions(context: context))  // <--- here
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Picker("Select action", selection: $selectedAction){
                    ForEach(actions) { action in
                        if action.title == true {
                            Text("\(action.action!)").tag(action)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Won’t this just create a new object every time?

Comment: yeah, it will create a new `Actions` every time, but it will not save it, unless you specifically want to save it. You can check this by adding `.onAppear{ print("---> actions: \(actions.count)") }`