# How can I use a list of names out of CoreData with a Picker in menuPickerStyle

Tags: xcode, core-data, swiftui, picker

I'm looking for a way to read a list of players from CoreData in order to select a single name with a menupickerstyle-picker. Displaying the entire list works fine.

this works fine:
Text("Number of players: (teams.count) ")
How con a display a single name?
Text("Players Name: (???????????) ")

Thx for any help.
Franz

//DataBase: teamsandscores Entity: Team,  Attributes: id as UUID and player as String

```
class CoreDataManager {

let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer

init() {
    persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "teamsandscores")
    persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
        if let error = error {
            fatalError("Core Data Store failed \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
    func updateTeam() {
        
        do {
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
        } catch{
            persistentContainer.viewContext.rollback()
        }
    }

    func deleteTeam(team: Team){
        
        persistentContainer.viewContext.delete(team)
        do {
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
        } catch{
            persistentContainer.viewContext.rollback()
            print("Failed to save context \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    
    
    func getAllTeams() -> [Team] {
        
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Team> = Team.fetchRequest()
        
        do{
            return try persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        }
        catch {
            return []
        }
    }
    
    func saveTeams(player: String){
        
        let teamCD = Team(context: persistentContainer.viewContext)
        teamCD.player = player
        do {
           try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("failed to save team name \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

```
    let coreDM: CoreDataManager
    
    @State private var playerHome : String = ""

    @State private var allPlayersCIndex = 1
    
    @State private var teams: [Team] = [Team]()
    
    private func populateTeams(){
        teams = coreDM.getAllTeams()
    }
    
    var body: some View{
            
            VStack{
                HStack{
                TextField("NewPlayer", text: $playerHome )
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                Button("Save") {
                    coreDM.saveTeams(player: playerHome)
                    populateTeams()
                    playerHome = ""
                }
                }
                List{
                    ForEach(teams, id: \.self) { name in
                        Text(name.player ?? "")
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                        indexSet.forEach { index in
                            let team = teams[index]
                            coreDM.deleteTeam(team: team)
                            populateTeams()
                        }
                                     })
                }
///works fine:
                Text("Number of players: \(teams.count) ")

///// I need help.

               Text("Players Name: \(???????????[0]) ")
                }
            HStack{
          
///?                    Picker("Player", selection: $allPlayersCIndex,
                            content: {
                            ForEach(teams, id: \.self) { name in
 ///??                               Text(name.player ?? "")
                                }
              
                            }

                    )
            }
```

Comment: *How can a display a single name?* Which one of the list? And your naming is a bit confusing. The name `Team` implies multiple players. Why not `Player` instead of `Team` and `name` instead of `player.`

Comment: Your selection variable, `allPlayersCIndex`, is not an index but the selected object so a Team in this case. You also need to use .tag for each item in the picker. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69454136/choosing-coredata-entities-from-form-picker) for instance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing CoreData Entities from form picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69454136/choosing-coredata-entities-from-form-picker)

Comment: I added these lines 
@State private var selectedPlayer: Team?    
 @FetchRequest(entity: Team.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var playersname: FetchedResults<Team> 

 Picker("Please choose a Player", selection: $selectedPlayer) {
 ForEach(Array(playersname), id: \.self) { playrs in   
 Text(playrs.player ?? "Unknown")
  .tag(playrs as? Team)
Now the UI is ok, but there is an empty list of names to select with the picker popup. Please excuse my misleading naming.