# SwiftUI @State weird wrappedValue behaviour

Tags: swiftui, binding, picker

So straight to the point i have this code:

```
struct DataModel {
    var option: String

}

struct ViewModel {
    var selected: String? = "1"
    var options = [DataModel(option: "1"), DataModel(option: "2"), DataModel(option: "3")]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("test", selection: aBinder()) {
                ForEach(viewModel.options, id: \.option) { option in
                    Text(option.option)
                }
            }
            .background(Color.red)
        }
    }
    
    func aBinder() -> Binding<String?> {
        Binding<String?> {
            viewModel.selected
        } set: { value in
            $viewModel.selected.wrappedValue = value
            print($viewModel.selected.wrappedValue)
        }
    }
}
```

The value of "selected" in the viewModel doesn't change.

This works:

```
struct DataModel {
    var option: String
}

struct ViewModel {
    var selected: String = "1"
    var options = [DataModel(option: "1"), DataModel(option: "2"), DataModel(option: "3")]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("test", selection: $viewModel.selected) {
                ForEach(viewModel.options, id: \.option) { option in
                    Text(option.option)
                }
            }
            
            Button("press me", action: { print(viewModel.selected) })
        }
    }
}
```

But that doesn't make any sense. in both cases i use a binding to store the current value. What is going on? I'm pretty new to swiftUI so i might have missed how something works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you can just do “viewModel.selected.wrappedValue = value”. The $ is when you want to pass a reference to the @State down to another view.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Aheze But wrappedValue is only on Bindings and States. Which would mean i would have to say viewModel.selected = value. But then it's a struct, which is immutable :/

Comment: The types don’t match selected is a String and the options are a DataModel. The types have to match exactly. Loos at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69454136/choosing-coredata-entities-from-form-picker/69467142#69467142)

Comment: @Vollan, sorry, I meant “viewModel.selected = value”. IIRC that should work even though it’s a struct, because “viewModel” is an State and they are special

Comment: Aheze, yes. States are different, but as the state itself is a struct with sub value, it wont work :/.

@loremipsum Thank you. It worked in my test code. i will try it live tomorrow and give feedback. Write answer if you wants some points ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types don’t match `selected` is a `String` and the `options` are a `DataModel`. The types have to match exactly.