# Core Data saving Object's relationship to existing Object

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

How do I save a Todo item and set its relationship to an existing Category if one already exists? I know how to create a new Category and set its relationship to the new Todo already as shown below. I'm doing this within a form.

`Category` is set to have `many` `Todos`.

```
        let category2 = Category(context: viewContext)
        category2.id = UUID()
        category2.title = "Fun"

        let todo = Todo(context: viewContext)
        todo.title = "Hi"
        todo.dueDate = Date.now
        todo.relationship = category2

        try? viewContext.save()

//todo.relationship = create a new Category if one doesn't exist, if it does exist, select that as the relationship. If no category, then do nothing
```

I have been following this solution here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1oWprQqLJY&t=483s and it has the same issue where a new "Origin" is created each time the button is pressed.

[image]

Comment: You fetch the existing category objects using a (NS)FetchRequest objects and use one of them

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69454136/choosing-coredata-entities-from-form-picker/69467142#69467142

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was fine I was just missing the merge policy which is explained here. If you are following along with Paul's HackingWithSwift videos make sure you do this...

This will handle duplicates along with the constraint set for the core data entity.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/ensuring-core-data-objects-are-unique-using-constraints

```
    self.container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
```

Comment: Just a heads up that Core Data unique constraints will not work if your eventual goal is to use CloudKit so that iCloud is the source of truth for your Core Data model (e.g. to share data across devices). You'll need to write your own deduplication methods.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup but I have no idea how to solve for that. @CALL-151

Comment: That will depend on what makes sense for your particular data model, but here's a conceptual approach:  1. Decide what constitutes a duplicate (e.g. if title and due date are the same, it's a duplicate). 2. Before saving, do a fetch request with a predicate constructed to find a duplicate. 3. if a duplicate exists, don't save.