# swiftui: problem with adding a property to data struct

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a struct:

```
struct Property: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name : String = ""
    var symbol : String = PropertySymbols.randomName()
    var address: String?
    var propertyArea: String?
    var meters : [Meter] = [Meter(name: "electricity"), Meter(name: "water")]
    
}

struct Meter: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name : String = ""
}

class PropertyData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var properties: [Property] = [
    Property(name: "Saks 85/1", meters: [Meter(name: "electricity")]),
    Property(name: "Saks 85/2", meters: [Meter(name: "electricity"), Meter(name: "water")]),
    Property(name: "Saks 85/3", meters: [Meter(name: "electricity"), Meter(name: "cold water"), Meter(name: "hot water")]),
    ]
}

@ObservedObject var data : PropertyData
    var property : Property
    @State var newMeter: String = ""
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form{
                Section {
                    TextField("Add another meter", text: $newMeter)
                    Button{
                        if newMeter != "" {
                            property.meters.append(Meter(name: newMeter))    //THAT IS THE PROBLEM
                            print(property.meters.count)
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Add a meter")
                    }.centerHorizontally()
                }
                ForEach(0..<property.meters.count, id:\ .self) {index in
                    Text(property.meters[index].name)
                }
                Section() {
                    Button("That's enough"){
                        print(property.meters)
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()}.centerHorizontally()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when in ContentView I try

apartment.meter.append(Meter(name:"water"))
I get

**Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable**

Can't get through that, tried @State and @Binding etc, it doesn't work, if I try as make @State var property - it changes here, but doesn't update the data...

Comment: try this: `apartment.meters.append(Meter(name:"water"))`, note the "s" in "meters"

Comment: no, it's a mistake here, i shortened the code for simplicity. The problem is that it doesn't allow me to add new METER from the VIEW, even when I try to make a mutating func

Comment: well, show us the code then, something we can replicate at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing here but `var property : Property` should be

```
@Binding var property : Property
```

`let` means that the variable won't change. `@Binding` is a two-way connection.

You will connect them in your previous view with something like this.

```
ForEach($data.properties, id:\.id){ $property 
    YourViewName(property: $property)
}
```

This question marks denote the two-way connection. Without them you are not going to be able to change the variable.

Comment: Yes, it works, but somehow it doesn't update the data model... so the parent view doesn't update:
```
Picker("Meters", selection: $metersPage) {
                    ForEach (0 ..< property.meters.count) {index in
                        Text(property.meters[index].name)
                    }
                }
```

Comment: changing to:
Picker("Meters", selection: $metersPage) {
                    ForEach (0 ..< property.meters.count, **id:\.self**) {index in
                        Text(property.meters[index].name)
                    }
                }

worked... 

THANKS A LOT, guys

Comment: @RomanR you don't have a `Picker` in your code. But you should be matching the type, don't use `count`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69454136/choosing-coredata-entities-from-form-picker/69467142#69467142) is an example, it is for CoreData but the concept is the same, the types have to match exactly and use the `tag` to specify what you want done.