# Swiftui Button image not changing on clicking until i click on another button

Tags: ios, button, swiftui

I know someone has asked a similar question already, but I still haven't solved the problem.

I have a HStack with 2 buttons that changes image upon click. The first button does not change on clicking until I click the other button, the second button updates correctly. The difference between the 2 buttons is that the first one’s action depends on the variable ‘museum.favorite’, which is a variable of the class Museum. The second one updates depending on the variable b’s value, which is a state variable declared in the same view.

I have been stuck on this for the past few days and would really appreciate if any one knows the reason behind & a way around this. The reason I want the button to update depending on the value of ‘museum.favorite’ is because I found that if I update according to a state variable declared in the same view (passing the variable as a parameter does not work either), then the image changes back to the default one (“heart” instead of “heart.fill”) soon after I change to another view.

Here is the code, thank you in advance!:

```
    
    var museum:Museum
    @State var a = false
    @State var b = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button {
                museum.favorite.toggle()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: museum.favorite == true ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
            }
            Button {
                b.toggle()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: b == true ? "star.fill" : "star")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let model = MuseumModel()
        Test(museum: model.museums[0])
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [swiftui: problem with adding a property to data struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70631716/swiftui-problem-with-adding-a-property-to-data-struct)

Comment: If museum is a class, like you say, it needs to be an ObservableObject and favorite needs to be a @Published property.

Comment: I have tried this already, but adding @Published to favourite gets the error: "Type 'Museum' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'". The class Museum is declared as --> class Museum : Identifiable, Decodable, ObservableObject {}. How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is a classic example of needing a minimal, reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found an easier approach.
At the of the `HStack`, add `.onAppear{}` and do a condition check so that the image updates itself across different views.

```
    import SwiftUI
    
    struct buttons: View {
        
        var museum:Museum
        @State var visitIcon = "figure.walk.circle"
        @State var heart = "heart"
        
        var body: some View {
            HStack(spacing:60){
                    Button(action: {
                        museum.visited.toggle()
                        if(museum.visited){
                            visitIcon = "figure.walk.circle.fill"
                        }
                        else{
                            visitIcon = "figure.walk.circle"
                        }
                    }, label: {
                        VStack{
                            Image(systemName:visitIcon).resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20).foregroundColor(.black)
                            
                            Text("Visited").foregroundColor(.black)
                        }
                    })
                    Button(action: {
                        museum.favorite.toggle()
                        if(museum.favorite){
                            heart = "heart.fill"
                        }
                        else{
                            heart = "heart"
                        }
                    }, label: {
                    
                        VStack{
                            Image(systemName:heart).resizable()
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20).foregroundColor(.black)
                            Text("Favorite").foregroundColor(.black)
                        }
                    })
            }.onAppear {
                if(museum.favorite){
                    visitIcon = "figure.walk.circle.fill"
                }
                else{
                    visitIcon = "figure.walk.circle"
                }
                if(museum.favorite){
                    heart = "heart.fill"
                }
                else{
                    heart = "heart"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```