# View closes/crashes after updating an object listed in a picker

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data, picker

I am having a view showing running workout details. In this view, I have Picker, allowing the user to select the pair of shoes used in the workout. Once the user selected the pair of shoes and presses the "Update" button, the mileage of the shoe shall update. The mileage is an attribute of the shoe entity (Core Data)

The update of the core data object works fine (data is updated as expected), but the view crashes. Initially I thought that it is a core data problem, but now I suppose that the picker struggles with updates on objects listed in the picker.

I was trying around and hence have partially still some unnecessary lines of code (I have to clean it up, once it works fine).

Here is how I declared the properties/variables:

```
@State private var wOshoes = [WorkoutShoeEntity]()
@State private var selectedShoe = ShoeEntity ()
@State private var unselectedShoe: ShoeEntity?
@State private var newShoe: ShoeEntity?
@State private var initialShoe = String()
@State private var buttonDisabled = true
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var shoes: FetchedResults<ShoeEntity>
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var workoutShoes: FetchedResults<WorkoutShoeEntity>
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
```

Here is the view:

```
HStack{
        Label("Summary", systemImage:"shoeprints.fill")
            .font(.headline)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
        Picker ("Select your shoes", selection: $selectedShoe){
            Text(initialShoe).tag(UUID())
            ForEach(shoes, id: \.self){ shoe in
                Text (shoe.name ?? "Fehlerteufel").tag(Optional(shoe))
                
            }
        }.onTapGesture {
            buttonDisabled.toggle()
        }
        Spacer()
        Button("Update"){
            updateMileage()
            buttonDisabled.toggle()
        }.disabled(buttonDisabled)
    }
    .padding(20)
    .onAppear(){
        initialShoe = "No shoe assigned..."
        getShoe()
        print(wOshoes.count)
        if (wOshoes.count>0){
            print ("schon schuhe dran")
            selectedShoe = getShoeDetails(shoeID: (wOshoes.first?.shoeID)!)
            initialShoe = getShoeName(shoeID: (wOshoes.first?.shoeID)!)
        }
        
        
    }
        
}
```

The updateMileage() functions is like this:

```
    func updateMileage(){
    
    if(wOshoes.count>0){
        print ("Bereits ein Schuh zugewiesen")
        unselectedShoe = getShoeDetails(shoeID: (wOshoes.first?.shoeID)!)
        let value = (unselectedShoe?.distance ?? 0.0) - (workout.distance ?? 0.0)
        updateShoeDistance(shoe: unselectedShoe!, newValue: value)
        
        let value1 = (selectedShoe.distance ?? 0.0) + (workout.distance ?? 0.0)
        
        updateShoeWorkAssignment(shoeWorkout: wOshoes.first!, shoe: selectedShoe)
        newShoe = getShoeDetails(shoeID: (selectedShoe.id)!)
        updateShoeDistance(shoe: selectedShoe.self, newValue: value1)
    }else{
        /*print ("noch kein Schuh zugewiesen")
        
        let value = (selectedShoe.distance ?? 0.0) + (workout.distance ?? 0.0)
        //updateShoeDistance(shoe: selectedShoe!.self, newValue: value)
        assignNewShoeToWorkout(shoeID: (selectedShoe.id)!, workoutID: workout.id)
       selectedShoe?.name = "ich habe es aktualisiert"
        
        newShoe = getShoeDetails(shoeID: (selectedShoe.id)!)
        //newShoe?.mainImage = "Das wäre Image"
        print (newShoe)*/
    }
    
    
}
```

and the updateDistance function is as follows:

```
func updateShoeDistance(shoe: ShoeEntity, newValue: Double){
    
    print(shoe.description)
    shoe.distance = newValue
    shoe.setValue(newValue, forKey: "distance")
    try? moc.save()
}
```

As mentioned the core data object is being updated, but the view closes after the update procedure. I don't get any error message in the console. I assume, that the problem is with the Picker.

Would anybody having some tipps for me?

Comment: Make `selectedShoe` optional and don't initiate it with an object. What does `ShoeEntity()` do by the way? Also if the app crashes you should have some error message in the console or a crash log in the Console app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing CoreData Entities from form picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69454136/choosing-coredata-entities-from-form-picker)

Comment: Note, `.tag(...)` in the `Picker`, should be of the same type as the `selectedShoe`. In your case, `ShoeEntity`, or Optional if change it to optional. You have `Text(initialShoe).tag(UUID())`
 that does not match, and so you will not be able to select it.

Comment: Thank you all for the swift replies! I tried to consider your suggestions and made selectedShoe optional and made to .tag() to ShoeEntity. But still it does not work. Interestingly, now I got the following error in the console: "**)" is invalid and does not have an associated tag, this will give undefined results."**The picker is now implemented as follows: `Picker ("Select your shoes", selection: $selectedShoe){
                ForEach(shoes, id: \.id){
                    Text ($0.name ?? "Fehlerteufel").tag($0 as ShoeEntity)
                }
            }`

Comment: It should be `.tag($0 as? ShoeEntity)` or `.tag(Optional($0))`.

Comment: I have seen problems initialising a UUID() in view ids like you have with the Text above the ForEach, leading to very strange problems. I think this is the issue personally. The ID is different on every rebuild of the body when in fact it is really a static view. What should be selected if you select that text in the Picker, no shoe selected? In which case set tag(nil). It needs to be the same type as the  Optional(shoe) which is the binding for the Picker, which nil is valid. The tag in the ForEach will also be a shoe value as it is iterating the FetchResults so can use tag( shoe ).