# SwiftUI Picker not binding

Tags: swiftui, binding, picker

I would like to create a list of categories and a list of items. For each item, I want it to user a picker for what category it beings to. I want the list at the bottom to show the item, and what category it belongs to. I don't think the picker is binding, and when I click save it only shows the item and not what category it belongs to.

```
struct CopyOfItemsView: View {
    private var listedItem: FetchedResults<Item>
    private var listedCategory: FetchedResults<Category>
    @State var categoryString: String = ""
    @State var nameString: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // add new category
            TextField("Enter Text Here", text: $categoryString)
            Button {
                let newlistedCategory = Category(context: viewContext)
                newlistedCategory.categoryString = categoryString
                save()
                categoryString = ""
            } label: {
                Text("Save")
            }
            // add new item
            TextField("Enter Text Here", text: $nameString)
            Picker("category", selection: $categoryString) {
                ForEach(listedCategory) { listedCategory in
                    Text(listedCategory.categoryString!)
                }
            }
            Button {
                let newlistedItem = Item(context: viewContext)
                newlistedItem.nameString = nameString
                newlistedItem.categoryString = categoryString
                save()
                nameString = ""
                categoryString = ""
            } label: {
                Text("Save")
            }

            // list
            ForEach(listedItem) { listedItem in
                HStack {
                    Text(listedItem.nameString ?? "")
                    Text(listedItem.categoryString ?? "")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func save() {
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `String` is not a `Category`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing CoreData Entities from form picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69454136/choosing-coredata-entities-from-form-picker)

Comment: Unrelated but you should set up a proper relationship between Item and Category

Comment: Unrelated (2), using the same `@State` property for a text field and a picker is a shortcut that could lead to some strange behavior and unexpected results. You should really have two `@State` properties instead.

Answer (score 1):

you need `tag`

```
Picker("category", selection: $categoryString) {
    ForEach(listedCategory) { listedCategory in
        Text(listedCategory.categoryString!)
            .tag(listedCategory.categoryString!)
    }
}
```